# JS implementation of ge_fromfe_frombytes_vartime

Tags: wallet, javascript

I'm working on JS implementation of Monero wallet. I got stuck with the `ge_fromfe_frombytes_vartime` method.

- Original code: https://github.com/monero-project/monero/blob/v0.17.1.9/src/crypto/crypto-ops.c#L2310-L2424
- Shen Noether's paper:  https://github.com/monero-project/research-lab/blob/master/whitepaper/ge_fromfe_writeup/ge_fromfe.pdf
- monero-agent code https://github.com/ph4r05/monero-agent/blob/21e53a4dcbc6d6aab6ade6262de523223bce1b11/monero_glue/xmr/core/ec_py.py#L842
- mininero code: https://github.com/monero-project/mininero/blob/c5fcee9d8ec8c302bca7fda8ce79b68e20d31c34/mininero.py#L238

Maybe somebody knows any JS implementation or more details explanation logic behind the `ge_fromfe_frombytes_vartime` method.

Answer (score 2):

According to the [CryptoNote Whitepaper](https://bytecoin.org/old/whitepaper.pdf), the hash-to-point algorithm is based on [this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/0706.1448.pdf).